# Get position of NSString in string - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, nsstring, nsurl

I am developing an iOS app and one of the things I need to do it to go over URLs and replace the first protocol section with my own custom protocol.

How can I delete the first few characters of a NSString before the "://"?

So for example I need convert the following:

```
http://website.com  -->  cstp://website.com
ftp://website.com  -->  oftp://website.com
https://website.com  -->  ctcps://website.com
```

The main problem I face, is that I can't just delete the first 'x' number of characters from the URL string. I have to detect how many characters there are till the "://" characters are reached.

So how can I count how many characters there are from that start of the string to the "://" characters?

Once I know this, I can then simply do the following to delete the characters:

```
int counter = ... number of characters ...
NSString *newAddress = [webURL substringFromIndex:counter];
```

Thanks for your time, Dan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
NSRange range = [urlString rangeOfString:@"://"];
```

`range.location` will give you the first index from where the `"://"` starts and you can use it as:

```
NSString *newAddress = [urlString substringFromIndex:range.location];
```

and append your prefix:

```
NSString *finalAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", prefixString, newAddress];
```

Answer (score 4):

`http://website.com` is a *URL*, and `http` is the *scheme* part of the URL. Instead of string manipulation I would recommend to use the
`NSURLComponents` class which is made exactly for this purpose: inspect, create and modify URLs:

```
NSString *originalURL = @"http://website.com";
NSURLComponents *urlcomp = [[NSURLComponents alloc] initWithString:originalURL];
if ([urlcomp.scheme isEqualToString:@"http"]) {
    urlcomp.scheme = @"cstp";
} else if ([urlcomp.scheme isEqualToString:@"ftp"]) {
    urlcomp.scheme = @"otfp";
}
// ... handle remaining cases ...

NSString *modifiedURL = [urlcomp string];
NSLog(@"%@", modifiedURL); // cstp://website.com
```

If the number of cases grows then a dictionary mapping is easier to
manage:

```
NSDictionary *schemesMapping = @{
       @"http"  : @"cstp",
       @"ftp"   : @"otfp"
       @"https" : @"ctcps" };
NSURLComponents *urlcomp = [[NSURLComponents alloc] initWithString:originalURL];
NSString *newScheme = schemesMapping[urlcomp.scheme];
if (newScheme != nil) {
    urlcomp.scheme = newScheme;
}
NSString *modifiedURL = [urlcomp string];
```

Comment: Wow! This makes a lot of sense. Just one thing, what about when a user copies in a URL link with no scheme. In my case I am simply just concatenating ```http://``` in front of it. But how would this code detect if there is no scheme?

Comment: @Supertecnoboff: `[[NSURLComponents alloc] initWithString:originalURL]` returns `nil` if `originalURL` is not a valid URL, e.g. if the scheme is missing.

Comment: Ok interesting. Thanks very much, I can't give you the tick I'm afraid, but I did up vote your answer. I think this is much more reliable method than the one above. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Supertecnoboff: You are welcome (and it is completely up to you which answer you want to accept, no problem at all)!